# JSXGraph: Is there a more robust metric for majorHeight?

Tags: jsxgraph

I recently discovered how flexibly one can actually draw axes. However, I struggle with grid lines for the ticks. I can calculate the required majorHeight and set it for any specific combination of canvas size and axis lengths.

But when the canvas is squashed, e.g. due to a too narrow browser window, the grid lines' length remains constant and they become too long. In the example below (sorry, I do not know a way to provide an MWE where the canvas can actually be squashed...), the y-axis' lines should run from 0 to 5 along the x-axis. But in a narrower window, these lines extend beyond the x-value of 5.

[MWE: Sine Function Parameters](https://jsfiddle.net/FLeupold/61Lkxb23/154/)

```
var brd = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('BOARDID0', {
    boundingbox: [-0.5, 3, 10, -3], axis: false });

var xAxis = brd.create('axis', [ [0,0],[5.4,0] ], {
    straightFirst: false, straightLast: false,
    withLabel: true, name: 't (s)',
    label: {position: 'rt', offset: [0, 15], anchorX: 'right' },
    ticks: {ticksDistance: 1, majorHeight: 267, tickEndings: [1,1],
        insertTicks: false, minorTicks: 1, minorHeight: 267,
        label: {anchorX: 'middle', anchorY: 'top', offset: [0,-3] } }
    });
var yAxis = brd.create('axis', [ [0,-2.4],[0,2.4] ], {
    straightFirst: false, straightLast: false,
    withLabel: true, name: 'y (m)',
    label: {position: 'rt', offset: [12, -3], anchorX: 'left' },
    ticks: {ticksDistance: 1, majorHeight:762, drawZero: true,
        insertTicks: false, minorTicks: 1, minorHeight: 762,
        label: {anchorX: 'right', anchorY: 'middle', offset: [-3,0] } }
    });
```

Is there maybe a better, more robust (and maybe simpler) way to fix the majorHeight?

Comment: "sorry, I do not know a way to provide an MWE where the canvas can actually be squashed": Indeed, due to regression in v1.4.4, JSXGraph does not react to canvas size changes, i.e. the `resizeObserver` is broken. The bug is meanwhile fixed in the sources, thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, `majorHeight` and `minorHeight` are given as constant pixel values. However, it is also possible to supply these values as functions. One possible solution is to supply the size of the ticks as a function in user coordinates and convert these into pixel values using `board.unitX` and `board.unitY`. For some reason, the user coordinates have to multiplied by two. Here is an example:

```
var xAxis = board.create('axis', [ [0,0],[5.4,0] ], {
    straightFirst: false, straightLast: false,
    withLabel: true, name: 't (s)', /* name: '$$x\\;\\mathrm{(m)}$$', */
    label: {position: 'rt', offset: [0, 15], anchorX: 'right', parse: false, fontSize: 12 },
    ticks: {ticksDistance: 1, 
        majorHeight: ()=>4*board.unitY, 
        minorHeight: ()=>4*board.unitY,
        tickEndings: [1,1],
        insertTicks: false, minorTicks: 1, 
        label: {anchorX: 'middle', anchorY: 'top', offset: [0,-3] } }
    });
var yAxis = board.create('axis', [ [0,-2.4],[0,2.4] ], {
    straightFirst: false, straightLast: false,
    withLabel: true, name: 'y (m)', /* name: '$$x\\;\\mathrm{(m)}$$', */
    label: {position: 'rt', offset: [12, -3], anchorX: 'left', parse: false, fontSize: 12 },
    ticks: {ticksDistance: 1, 
        majorHeight: ()=>10*board.unitX,
        minorHeight: ()=>10*board.unitX,
        drawZero: true,
        insertTicks: false, minorTicks: 1, 
        label: {anchorX: 'right', anchorY: 'middle', offset: [-3,0] } }
    });
```

At https://jsfiddle.net/hrt56j1e/1/ there is a working example using v1.4.3.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution! Please allow me a follow-up question: As far as I understand, one can at the moment either draw tickEndings on either side or symmetrically on both sides of an axis. So one cannot have these lines run asymmetrically, say from -1 to +2 along the x-axis for y-axis ticks, right? Would it maybe be an option to make tickEndings accept decimal numbers between 0 and 1 to scale the tick endings differently on both sides of an axis?

Comment: Indeed, the attribute `tickEndings:[neg, pos]` allows to scale the tick lengths asymmetrically. Just take e.g. `tickEndings:[1, 0.5]`. Negative values are interpreted as infinity.

Comment: That is great! Shame on me for not even trying it. 
So tickEndings is actually more capable that documented at https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Ticks.html#tickEndings